# Multiple NFTs in a single scene

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, 3dsmax, artoolkit

I am creating a desktop application using ARToolkit and Unity. Basically it scans the images from the book and generate 3D models based on the marker. It is working perfectly with a single NFT marker. Now I am having trouble on how do I do this same procedure with multiple NFT markers in the same scene. ? 
Please help in this matter. ThankYou.

Answer (score 1):

best starting point is to have a look at the TwoNFTMarkerScene that comes with the ARToolKit for Unity plugin. There you see how to work with multiple NFTs in the same scene.